# How to use ASYNCIO through multi python files?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

(I apologize for my English, I'm French ^^')

I stated with Asyncio method, and I have a little problem.
I have 3 python files, main.py, commands.py and Client.py (all names are for examples), and I try to run multiple tasks, at the same time, in commands.py thought my main.py. But each task waits the previous task for started.

In Client.py (but not care, I simplify this, it's just for context)

```py
class StartClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port = 0):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.port = port

    def get_name(self) :
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_socket.connect(("localhost", self.port))
        self.client_socket.setblocking(0)
        self.client_socket.sendall("get_name")
        reply = self.client_socket.recv(4098)
        print (f"reply from {self.port}: ", reply)
        return reply
```

In Commands.py

```py
async def client_get_name(port):
    print (f"start_client {port}")
    client = StartClient(port)
    name = client.get_name()
    return name

async def run_mutl_clients():
    tasks = {}
    ports = [61,65,67]
    for port in ports:
        tasks[str(port)]= asyncio.create_task(client_get_name(port))
        
    for port, task in tasks.items() : 
        scene_name = await task
        opened_instances[str(port)] = scene_name
    

    MyPySideDialog.launch(opened_instances)
```

In my main.py

```py
class FabulousPySideApp():
    def __init__(self):
    self.run_async()

    def run_async(self): 
        asyncio.run(Commands.run_mutl_clients())
```

So, I wish to start multiple `client_get_name()` at the same time (one by ports), and waiting they are finished to send `opened_instances` to `MyPySideDialog` (this just an ui for users, just no care about that).
`StartClient()` is a function who started a socket client (by type, by port). This is a bit too long if I have many ports to open, one by one. I want to start all ports in the same time, waiting their answers.
Expected :

```
>>start_client 61
>>start_client 65
>>start_client 67
>>reply from 61, "name1"
>>reply from 65, "name2"
>>reply from 67, "name3"
[Finished in 2s]
```

Reality :

```
>>start_client 61
>>reply from 61, "name1"
>>start_client 65
>>reply from 65, "name2"
>>start_client 67
>>reply from 67, "name3
[Finished in 6s]
"
```

I think, I was missed some things...
Someone can help me :)

Thanks

Comment: What are `Commands`, `MyPySideDialog`, and `StartClient`? Also, please fix your indentation. Ideally, provide an example that people here can run to see the problem you're seeing and please describe what happens and what you expected to happen instead. The problem is your tasks currently run one after the other and you expected them to run in parallel? `asyncio` doesn't run anything in parallel by itself, it just runs code asynchronously, which is not the same - that is, your results could come in different order, if there's reason for them to do so, but routines would still run one at a time

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was a complex "architecture", I try to simplify at most, sorry about that.
I'll edit my message, with what I expect. 
However, I wish to start multiple `client_get_name()` at the same time (one by ports), and waiting they are finished to send `opened_instances` to `MyPySideDialog` (this just an ui for users, just no care about that).
`StartClient()` is a function who started a socket client. This is a bit too long if I have many ports to open, one by one. I want to start all ports in the same time, waiting their answers. 
I hope it's more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the code:

```
for port, task in tasks.items() : 
    scene_name = await task
    opened_instances[str(port)] = scene_name
```

in the line `scene_name = await task`. What that line means is: *"stop THIS function (`run_mutl_clients`) until the task is done and run OTHER function in the meanwhile"*

For running all tasks at the same time you can rewrite your code as:

```
async def run_mutl_clients():
    
    ports = [61,65,67]
    tasks = [client_get_name(port) for port in ports]

    instances = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    opened_instances = {
        port: instance 
        for (port, instance) in zip(ports, instances)
    }

    MyPySideDialog.launch(opened_instances)
```